# How to make div extend to the bottom of the screen regardless of resolution?

Tags: html, css, height, overflow

For specific pages in my document (where the text content on the page does not extend to the bottom of the screen), the div actually cuts off as opposed to being extended to the bottom of the display.

When I zoom out, the div does not grow with the body of the page. I tried to set it to 100% to no avail.

Do you know what I'm missing here? Tried to play around with the overflow-y property (applied it to "mainContainer" which contains floated children) without any luck either.

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; color:#25282a;  }
p { font-family: 'Pt Sans', sans-serif; }

body{
background: white; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #EAE8D8 0%, #EAE8D8 50%, white 50%, white 100%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #EAE8D8 0%, #EAE8D8 50%, white 50%, white 100%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #EAE8D8 0%, #EAE8D8 50%, white 50%, white 100%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #EAE8D8 0%, #EAE8D8 50%, white 50%, white 100%);
}

html { /*height:100%;*/ }
body { /*height:100%;*/ }

.menuDiv                { height:100px; width:100%; background:#25282a; margin:0 auto;  }
.mainContainer          { height:100%; max-width:1100px; min-width:700px; width:90%; overflow:hidden; height:100%; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;  margin:0 auto; }
.leftDiv                { height:100%; width:23%; background:#EAE8D8; float:left; }
.rightDiv               { height:100%; width:74%; background:white; float:left; padding-left:3%; padding-bottom:100px; }

.leftDivContainer       { width:100%; }
.menuList               { max-width:1100px; min-width:700px; width:90%; margin:0 auto;  }
.menuList li            { font-size:23px; width:16.66%; font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; background:#25282a; display:block; float:left; text-align:center; }
.menuList li a          { color:white; text-decoration:none; display:block; height:70px; padding-top:30px; }
.menuList li a:hover    { color:#41A4EE; cursor:pointer; background:#25282a; }

.subMenu                { position:absolute; z-index:100; }
.subMenu li             { float:none; text-align:left; display:block; /*width:100%;*/ width:225px; }
.subMenu li a           { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; height:30px; display:block; padding-right:10px; padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px; }
.subMenu li a:hover     { background:#25282a; }

.job_seekers_list,.employers_list,.about_list { display:none; }
.pageHeading { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size:20px; width:100%; color:#25282a; padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:7px; }

.leftList li { margin-left:20px; list-style-type:square; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; color:#24282a; font-size:16px; }
.leftList li a { text-decoration:none;}

.rightDivTitle { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; color:white; background:#25282a; padding-bottom:3px; padding-left:7px; text-align:left; }
.rightDivSubtitle { font-size:18px; }
.rightDivSubtitle2 { font-size:15px; }
.rightDivSubtitle, .rightDivSubtitle2 { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; padding-bottom:8px; font-weight:bold; color:#41A4EE; text-align:left; }
.rightDivContent { /* white-space: pre-wrap; */ font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size:15px; margin:0 auto; }

.rightDivList li { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; margin-left:20px; list-style-type:square; font-size:15px; }
.rightDivContentTable { width:100%; }
.rightDivContentTable td{ font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 15px; width:24%; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test_css.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="core_serv.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menuDiv">
<ul class="menuList">
  <li> <a href="home">HOME</a> </li>
  <li class="job_seekers_opt">
    <a href="#">JOB SEEKERS</a>
    <ul class="job_seekers_list subMenu">
      <li> <a href="search_jobs">Search Jobs</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="seek_bus_units">Our Business Units</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="tips">Tips</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="send_resume">Send Us Your Resume</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="faq">FAQ</a> </li>
  <li class="employers_opt">
    <a href="#">EMPLOYERS</a>
    <!--<a href=/employers>EMPLOYERS</a>-->
    <ul class="employers_list subMenu">
      <li> <a href="emp_bus_units">Business Units & Recruitment Expertise</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="staffing_opts">Staffing Options</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="emp_company_lit">Company Literature</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="testimonials">Testimonials</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="emp_contact">Contact</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="industries_serviced">Industries Serviced</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="about_opt">
    <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
    <ul class="about_list subMenu">
      <li> <a href="company_prof">Company Profile</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="mission_statement">Mission Statement</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="privacy_policy">Privacy Policy</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="about_company_lit">Company Literature</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="casl_compliance">CASL Compliance</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="accessibility">Accessiblity</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="contact">CONTACT</a> </li>
</ul>
  </div>
  <div class="mainContainer">
<div class="leftDiv">
  <h1 class="pageHeading"> Our Business Units</h1>
  <ul class="leftList">
    <li><a href="search_jobs">Search Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="seek_bus_units">Our Business Units</a></li>
    <li><a href="tips">Tips</a></li>
    <li><a href="send_resume">Send Us Your Resume</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="rightDiv">
  <br/><br/>
  <h1 class="rightDivTitle">Our Business Units</h1>
  <br/><br/>
  <p class="rightDivContent">
    Our recruitment and staffing consultants have experience placing professionals in the following areas:
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <ul class="rightDivList">
      <li>Engineering</li>
      <li>Executive and Management</li>
      <li>Information Technology</li>
      <li>Insurance and Financial</li>
      <li>Light Industrial</li>
      <li>Technical and Operations</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you meant when you say you zoom out. Are you trying to make it responsive and you meant you resize window viewport ?

Comment: Yes exactly. 

If the text content does not extend past the bottom of the window viewport, the div cuts off at that point. I want "mainContainer" to extend to the very bottom regardless of how much content is inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncomment

```
html { /*height:100%;*/ }
body { /*height:100%;*/ }
```

and replace `height: 100%` with `min-height: 100%` at `#mainContainer`

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; color:#25282a;  }
p { font-family: 'Pt Sans', sans-serif; }

body{
background: white; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #EAE8D8 0%, #EAE8D8 50%, white 50%, white 100%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #EAE8D8 0%, #EAE8D8 50%, white 50%, white 100%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #EAE8D8 0%, #EAE8D8 50%, white 50%, white 100%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #EAE8D8 0%, #EAE8D8 50%, white 50%, white 100%);
}

html { height:100%; }
body { height:100%; }

.menuDiv                { height:100px; width:100%; background:#25282a; margin:0 auto;  }
.mainContainer          { min-height: calc(100% - 100px); max-width:1100px; min-width:700px; width:90%; height:100%; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px;  margin:0 auto; }
.leftDiv                { height:100%; width:23%; background:#EAE8D8; float:left; }
.rightDiv               { height:100%; width:74%; background:white; float:left; padding-left:3%; padding-bottom:100px; }

.leftDivContainer       { width:100%; }
.menuList               { max-width:1100px; min-width:700px; width:90%; margin:0 auto;  }
.menuList li            { font-size:23px; width:16.66%; font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; background:#25282a; display:block; float:left; text-align:center; }
.menuList li a          { color:white; text-decoration:none; display:block; height:70px; padding-top:30px; }
.menuList li a:hover    { color:#41A4EE; cursor:pointer; background:#25282a; }

.subMenu                { position:absolute; z-index:100; }
.subMenu li             { float:none; text-align:left; display:block; /*width:100%;*/ width:225px; }
.subMenu li a           { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; height:30px; display:block; padding-right:10px; padding-left:10px; padding-top:10px; }
.subMenu li a:hover     { background:#25282a; }

.job_seekers_list,.employers_list,.about_list { display:none; }
.pageHeading { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size:20px; width:100%; color:#25282a; padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:7px; }

.leftList li { margin-left:20px; list-style-type:square; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; color:#24282a; font-size:16px; }
.leftList li a { text-decoration:none;}

.rightDivTitle { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; color:white; background:#25282a; padding-bottom:3px; padding-left:7px; text-align:left; }
.rightDivSubtitle { font-size:18px; }
.rightDivSubtitle2 { font-size:15px; }
.rightDivSubtitle, .rightDivSubtitle2 { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; padding-bottom:8px; font-weight:bold; color:#41A4EE; text-align:left; }
.rightDivContent { /* white-space: pre-wrap; */ font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size:15px; margin:0 auto; }

.rightDivList li { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; margin-left:20px; list-style-type:square; font-size:15px; }
.rightDivContentTable { width:100%; }
.rightDivContentTable td{ font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 15px; width:24%; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test_css.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="core_serv.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="menuDiv">
   <ul class="menuList">
    <li> <a href="home">HOME</a> </li>
    <li class="job_seekers_opt">
     <a href="#">JOB SEEKERS</a>
     <ul class="job_seekers_list subMenu">
           <li> <a href="search_jobs">Search Jobs</a> </li>
           <li> <a href="seek_bus_units">Our Business Units</a> </li>
           <li> <a href="tips">Tips</a> </li>
           <li> <a href="send_resume">Send Us Your Resume</a> </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="faq">FAQ</a> </li>
       <li class="employers_opt">
     <a href="#">EMPLOYERS</a>
         <!--<a href=/employers>EMPLOYERS</a>-->
         <ul class="employers_list subMenu">
           <li> <a href="emp_bus_units">Business Units & Recruitment Expertise</a> </li>
           <li> <a href="staffing_opts">Staffing Options</a> </li>
           <li> <a href="emp_company_lit">Company Literature</a> </li>
           <li> <a href="testimonials">Testimonials</a> </li>
           <li> <a href="emp_contact">Contact</a> </li>
           <li> <a href="industries_serviced">Industries Serviced</a> </li>
         </ul>
       </li>
    <li class="about_opt">
     <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
     <ul class="about_list subMenu">
      <li> <a href="company_prof">Company Profile</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="mission_statement">Mission Statement</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="privacy_policy">Privacy Policy</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="about_company_lit">Company Literature</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="casl_compliance">CASL Compliance</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="accessibility">Accessiblity</a> </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="contact">CONTACT</a> </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="mainContainer">
   <div class="leftDiv">
    <h1 class="pageHeading"> Our Business Units</h1>
    <ul class="leftList">
     <li><a href="search_jobs">Search Jobs</a></li>
     <li><a href="seek_bus_units">Our Business Units</a></li>
     <li><a href="tips">Tips</a></li>
     <li><a href="send_resume">Send Us Your Resume</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="rightDiv">
    <br/><br/>
    <h1 class="rightDivTitle">Our Business Units</h1>
    <br/><br/>
    <p class="rightDivContent">
     Our recruitment and staffing consultants have experience placing professionals in the following areas:
     <br/>
     <br/>
     <ul class="rightDivList">
      <li>Engineering</li>
      <li>Executive and Management</li>
      <li>Information Technology</li>
      <li>Insurance and Financial</li>
      <li>Light Industrial</li>
      <li>Technical and Operations</li>
     </ul>
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
          Very long content here <br />
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this, but when I have content in "mainContainer" that extends past the viewport/display screen, the content gets cut off and there's no scroll bar.

Comment: remove `overflow: hidden` at `#mainContainer`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the content you want to be displayed on the size of the page with a container, then set this container height and width to `100vh`. The `vh` property gets the viewport of where the page is being displayed and adjusts it automaticaly.